# Eclipse Neon, Open perspective does not have svn

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

Good day folks, I've been trying to install plugin for eclipse neon with subclipse or subversion but I still can't see any svn in my open perspective nor my team.
I updated my eclipse neon but still no result on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to delete directory "eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.update" and restart your eclipse.

Comment: I deleted the file but open perspective still don't have svn repository.

Comment: if the svn plugin is installed in "eclipse/dropins", try to make a new file "svn.link" in "eclipse/dropins" directory with the content being :path=eclipse/dropins/svn

Comment: I havent get the chance to try this because I uninstall my eclipse and get a fresh installation and redo every step which solved the issues. I figure that your way might help cause its some issue with the path , i guess. Thank you for showing me the help

Comment: my pleasure and congratulations.